# How to display Client Time Zone & TimeZone Abbrevations?

Tags: .net, asp.net, internationalization, timezone, culture

I am creating a asp.net 2.0 website. It display all the registered candidate with registered date. I am storing all the date in database as UniversalDate, Now want to display the date based on client culture and Time zone.

I am able to get Time Zone offset using javascript but how to shows Time Zone Abbrevation correctly, because there are someOffset is same.

So please let me know how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand that correctly:

Your problem is, you get time zone offset from web browser with JavaScript function getTimeZoneOffset(), send that out to server and upon displaying, you are facing the problem: which time zone to use?

Basically, there is no need to add time zone designator if it is user default one. By default one, I mean Local. In that case you need to care about correct offset only. Of course, it might be a problem for historical data: if there is more than one time zone that shares (currently) the same offset, but offset changes on different dates, you might print incorrect date and time for few records.

How to avoid it? The only way is to add time zone information to user's profile and give user an ability to choose her time zone from the list. You can easily obtain the list from `TimeZoneInfo` (and this is the class you would need to use to perform calculations; some entries will be duplicated intentionally/for historical reasons):

```
// gives you the list of time zones
var timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
foreach(var timeZone in timeZones)
{
    // gives you the UTC offset and list of cities this entry regards to
    // this is the best what you can display to user
    string name = timeZone.DisplayName;
    // ...
}
```

If you want to use this method, you may want to add information saying "All dates and times according to ... time zone. Change your time zone here.". That's it.
The only problem I have, DisplayName property is suppose to give me localized name, but it always show me the name in current server culture :/